# Angular 6 Karma/Jasmine Unit test case for dynamically added component

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a component in which i am dynamically adding another chart component. Here is the code:

```
appendBarChart(historicalData, key, type) {

    // Create component dynamically inside the ng-template
    const componentFactory = 
      this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(this.injectableComponentClass);

    const viewContainerRef = this.viewContainer;
    viewContainerRef.clear();
    const componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);

                             ....
    componentRef.instance.width = 300;
   }
```

Here is the test case:

```
  it('Should append historical data', inject([LineBarChartComponent], (childComponent: LineBarChartComponent) => {
component.appendBarChart(historicalData, 8, 'group');
fixture.detectChanges();
expect(childComponent.maxValue).toBe(5);
expect(childComponent.lineWithBar).toHaveBeenCalled();
}));
```

When I execute this test case, I get the following error:
Cannot read property "nativeElement" of undefined.

The child component has the following code:

```
constructor(private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {
    this.elem = this.viewContainerRef.element.nativeElement;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You shouldn't be injecting component through DI.

Comment: @yurzui Can you please elaborate.I am new to Angular unit testing.

Comment: `inject([LineBarChartComponent]` this part of your code can lead to this error. Angular instantiates component as a class but it can't resolve viewContainerRef because it is only available if component is being instantiates as a normal component with template. You should never inject component this way

Comment: @yurzui: Thanks!! but i have tried it without the inject also.

Comment: Can you please include all your spec file as well as all related components?

Comment: @yurzui: the code is too large to obfuscate :-(

Comment: @yurzui: Can you help in writing a test case for a dynamic component with viewContainerRef reference?

Comment: Sure, but can you at least include the whole code of `appendBarChart` method and code of `LineBarChartComponent`?

Comment: @yurzui: sorry, I cannot do that as it is all proprietary code. :-(